# Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.3 - HP X360 Convertible - Keyboard not working after installation

Tags: drivers, keyboard

i upgraded my ssd and installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.3. While the Ubuntu installalation process the keyboard and trackpad worked fine, but after the first reboot booth are not working anymore. 
I had the same issue with Windows 10 (no keyboard/trackpad after installation) and after digging hours in the internet i found the solution. The Intel Sensor Hub driver had to be disabled and after that both devices worked again. I could figure if its caused because a faulty driver or a faulty batch of hardware.

Now i need help and advice how to replicate the Windows solution for Ubuntu/Linux.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hid/intel-ish-hid.txt